# Elegant way to pass data to event handler?

Tags: java, structure, organization

We have a webapp in Java where a user can subscribe to receive emails about certain events. They can provide the message they'd like to receive with parameters they can use such as `%DATE%` or `%TOTAL_DOWNLOADS%` which will be replaced with the appropriate values.

Currently, the code that replaces the parameters with their values is with the code for each specific event. For the event when another user downloads your file, for example, we have code like:

```
handleFileDownload(){
    ...
    if(user.notifyOnFileDownload){
        String message = user.fileDownloadNotifyMessage.replaceAll("%DATE%", user.formatDate(new Date())).replaceAll("%TOTAL_DOWNLOADS%", ...);
        ...
        sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

..or for personal messages:

```
handlePersonalMessage(){
    ...
    if(user.notifyOnPersonalMessage){
        String message = user.personalMessageNotifyMessage.replaceAll("%DATE%", user.formatDate(new Date())).replaceAll("%TOTAL_DOWNLOADS%", ...)
            .replaceAll("%SENDER%", sendingUser.username);
        ...
        sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Having the code for handling the parameters in multiple places makes it really difficult to add any new parameters or change how we handle existing ones, since all the places that send the notification messages would have to be updated. It seems like a much better idea to centralize this code such as doing:

```
class User{
    ...
    handleNotificationsForEvent(EventType et){
        if(!subscribedToEventType(et)) return;
        String message = getMessageForEventType(et);
        message = message.replaceAll("%DATE%", user.formatDate(new Date())).replaceAll("%TOTAL_DOWNLOADS%", ...);
        ...
        sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

so that the other code becomes:

```
handleFileDownload(){
    ...
    user.handleNotificationsForEvent(EventType.FILE_DOWNLOAD);
}


handlePersonalMessage(){
    ...
    user.handleNotificationsForEvent(EventType.PERSONAL_MESSAGE);
}
```

Many of the parameters are specific to the event, though, so the code for the event would either have to send the necessary data or do the replacing for those specific parameters itself. With personal messages, for example, the name of the sender and the subject of the personal message are two parameters.

The best I can think of is to create a class for holding the data and populate the necessary fields in the event handler:

```
class EventData{
    public String personalMessageSender;
    public String personalMessageSubject;
    public String downloadedFileName;
}

handleFileDownload(){
    ...
    EventData ed = new EventData();
    ed.downloadedFileName = fileName;
    user.handleNotificationsForEvent(EventType.FILE_DOWNLOAD, ed);
}

handlePersonalMessage(){
    ...
    EventData ed = new EventData();
    ed.personalMessageSender = sender;
    user.handleNotificationsForEvent(EventType.PERSONAL_MESSAGE, ed);
}
```

.. this seems too convoluted though.

**How can I centralize the handling of parameters in the notification messages given that I'm going to sometimes need data specific to the event causing the notification?**

Comment: You might use a template mechanism. There are many available. Like the [Apache Velocity Engine](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html).

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your requirements.  Why have an `EventType` at all?  Do all `EventType.FILE_DOWNLOAD` have exactly the same message?  I think there must be a better object oriented way to handle this that an explicit type token.

Comment: @markspace, So the handler knows which message to use.